# CImg throws exception randomnly

Tags: c++, cimg

I have a code which loads an image file, writes to a pixel in the image and saves the image. This method is called in a loop and every time, the image will be loaded, one of its pixel will be written a value and then, the image is saved. Some pixels are written successfully. But sometime before the loop ends, CImg throws an exception,

*** cmg::fopen(): Failed to open file 'kalyan.bmp' wih mode 'wb'.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
void FrameBuffer::writePixelToImage(int x, int y, Color c)
   {
std::cout << "Kalyan! in writePixelToImage" << endl;

string str = _filename;
CImg <unsigned char> outPutImage;
outPutImage.load(str.c_str());

std::cout << "Kalyan! after loading in writePixeltoImage" << endl;
std::cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << endl;
    outPutImage(x, y, 0, 0) = c.red;
outPutImage(x, y, 0, 1) = c.green;
outPutImage(x, y, 0, 2) = c.blue;

std::cout << "Kalyan! after writing color in writePixeltoImage" << endl;

outPutImage.save(str.c_str());
}
```

The function writePixelToImage is called several times in a loop.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Off topic: Why keep reopening and loading the file? Why not open, cache, edit cache, save cache when done?

Comment: On topic: Consider what happens if a file write is delayed at the OS or drive firmware. You may have closed it, but is the file in a state where it can be reopened when your program swings around a few microseconds later? Some number of open-edit-write-closes could be bogged down in a buffer somewhere waiting for processing and the exception is a manifestation of the OS giving you the finger because the buffer is full.

Comment: Makes sense! I will just try to halt the process for sometime within each iteration and see if I am getting any errors. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yup! @user4581301: what you pointed out was true! I basically, waited for sometime between successive reads and I didn't get the error again. Thanks!